# How to write mysql5 query for finding duplicate rows from a table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi I have a table like this

```
ID   UserName
1     test@test.com
2     test@test.com
3     john@stack.com
4     test@test.com
5     adam@stack.com
6     john@stack.com
```

I need an output like this. I need only repeated rows list. How can I create this kind of an output using mysql query.

```
ID   UserName           Count
1     test@test.com       3
2     john@stack.com      2
```

Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Why `john@stack.com` has an `ID` of `2` in the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the ID is not unique so its a bit not logical to get the sum of unique UserName from the table.

If the ID is not required we can get the result from single query.

```
SELECT UserName, COUNT(UserName) AS Count
FROM TableName GROUP BY UserName
HAVING COUNT(UserName) > 1;
```

But in the case of ID in the result it will be a more complicated query including sub-query and inner table.

Comment: Hi you r using SUM it will not work. I tried this its working
SELECT UserName, COUNT(UserName) AS Count
FROM TableName GROUP BY UserName
HAVING COUNT(UserName) > 1;

Comment: It's not logical to `SUM` usernames. You can `COUNT` them though.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem some time ago and solved it like this (as far as I remember):

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA INNER JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT MAX(id) as id, type_id, temp FROM tableA GROUP BY type_id, temp) AS t
ON tableA.id = t.id
AND tableA.type_id = t.type_id
AND tableA.temp = t.temp
```

You join the table with itself selecting the ids that are duplicate. The fields that should be tested against duplicate values are in this case `type_id` and `temp`. If you need more or less fields that should be considered as duplicates you can adjust the fields.

I don't know if this helps in your case and if it can be done in a more simple way, so I'm prepared for downvotes ;-)

Edit: removed last condition `AND tableA.id < t.id` as suggested by ypercube because it leads to 0 results.

Comment: Your query will show exactly `0` rows. You have both `tableA.id = t.id` `AND tableA.id < t.id` in the joining conditions.

Comment: If you remove the last condition, it will work. But there is no reason for such complexity. A simple GROUP BY can solve most such problems.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Yeah, as I said I doubt is was the most simplest way, but at least I wanted to share this solution.

Comment: Welcome. You can also remove the `DISTINCT` from your subquery. It's redundant there because of the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: And what you propose can be helpful in situations when one wants to show more rows (that the grouped ones) from the table.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to pull the following data:

- First ID for a given UserName
- The UserName itself
- The total number of IDs for that UserName

This query should do the trick:

```
SELECT
  MIN(id),
  UserName,
  COUNT(id)
FROM users
GROUP BY UserName;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT UserName
     , COUNT(*) AS `Count` 
FROM tableX
GROUP BY UserName
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is the right answer.

```
SELECT UserName, COUNT(UserName) AS Count
FROM TableName GROUP BY UserName
HAVING COUNT(UserName) > 1;
```

Comment: Then accept Talha's answer that has this. You don't need to post it as an answer yourself.

Comment: Also note that `COUNT(*)` is faster in MySQL than `COUNT(a_field)`. And in this case will have same results.